# Limiting result in DevExpress ASPxGridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

i want show to data result based on top result in ASPxGridView, is there any property which handle that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways of solving this, server side, UI side, hybrid...

Server side means you have a stored procedure on the SQL Server which contains a TOP x in the select.

UI side means you specify paging and a pageSize of X in the Grid and even if this would work is not so good because in any case the SQL Server will return all records to the web server over the network.

many different ways to implement hybrid solutions like using bindToLinq methods or other ORM approaches which would generate the TOP X for you depending on the settings and usage of the grid.

this as introduction, please show us how you are fetching the data and binding the grid to the result set.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dave, i use XPO Data Source to bind data result,

Comment: good, XPO should support server side paging and sorting, grouping and filtering by design, you should probably only set the PageSize in the grid and you are done!

Comment: no, i mean if we have 10 data i'll just show five data, i want to make PageSize = 1 and Pagination button just show 5 button. Is it clear enough?